# Google code formatter for Zeppelin leading to formatting changes in unchanged code

Tags: apache-zeppelin, formatter

I have downloaded Zeppelin with tag 0.8.1 and as specified in contributions guidelines, I tried using google formatter for intellij as well eclipse formatter via following links:

https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/eclipse-java-google-style.xml

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/styleguide/gh-pages/intellij-java-google-style.xml

However if I apply formatting to freshly checked out code, both of them leads to code formatting changes specific to tabs and line width.

Please point me correct formatter for same or any pointers what I am doing wrong.

Sample output after formatting :

[image: After applying google code formatting to freshly checked out code]

Changes in comment :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `checkstyle.xml` from `_tools` directory.

https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/master/_tools/checkstyle.xml

Comment: Not sure, if I am really doing something stupid. Added screenshot of problem i am facing. As suggested applied checkstyle and it looks to work fine as it don't gives any error with code formatted via google style. However applying formatting leading too many diffs in unchanged code thus making code review a bit cumbersome.

Comment: You could simplify code review by separate commits for check-style changes and fixes/features.

Comment: hmmm sounds a bit odd as to me both code review and check style lives as part of single PR. However is there some way to get the same code formatter settings which has been used while check in the code original zeppelin code. It would be really very helpful.